# yfinance stuck at 11:30 am

Tags: python, yfinance

I am trying to build a discord stock bot and I am trying to get data from yfinance, put it in a chart and send it, but when I do that yfinance is not sending all the hours :
getting data

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

            stock = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, period="1d", interval="30m")
            return stock['Adj Close']
```

[image: Chart]
The hour in my country is 6 pm
The chart is stuck at 11:30 all the time.
btw, the response is also stuck at 11:30 so is not a graph issue

Comment: `The chart is stuck at 11:30 all the time` do you mean, no matter what time of day it is, the chart is always stuck at 11:30? Regardless of whether it's 6PM, 12PM, 8AM, or whatever? If it's just showing this right now, then my thought is that it could be a time zone issue, and that you're 6 horus ahead of the timestamps coming back from the API. For the data coming back from the API, do you know what time zone it is? Do you know that it is being converted to your local time, or is it possible that it's just a different time zone and you're not converting anything?

Comment: @RandomDavis yes the chart is stuck at 11:30 all the time, actually I do not think it is a zone issue, a while back I had a different code for this (almost the same) and it worked but I do not remember how it was exactly

Comment: Looks like the project's [official issues page](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues) has a few posts about Yahoo Finance troubles; so, it seems that that library maybe has to be frequently updated in order for it to be able to pull Yahoo Finance data. I suggest making sure the library is up to date, and also posting your issue to the issues page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't see any problem here.

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get the data for the stock AAPL
start = '2022-01-01'
end = '2022-06-16'

data = yf.download('SBUX', start, end)


data = data.reset_index()
data

data.dtypes


# re-name field from 'Adj Close' to 'Adj_Close'
data = data.rename(columns={"Adj Close": "Adj_Close"})
data


data = data.loc[:,['Date','Adj_Close']]
       

# Plot all the close prices
# ((data.pct_change()+1).cumprod()).plot(figsize=(10, 7))


plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5), dpi=100)
plt.plot(data['Date'], data['Adj_Close'], label='Starbucks Stock Price')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('USD')
plt.title('Figure 2: Starbucks Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Run this: pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir
Thanks try it again.

Also, see this.

https://pypi.org/project/fix-yahoo-finance/